# JavaFx: How to observe Anchorpane while application is running?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

How to check if inside anchorpane there is some node exist or not using observable or binding right now I'm using if statement like this:

```
if(anchorPane().getChildren().size()>0){
    GridPane table = (GridPane) anchorPane().getChildren().get(0);
    for(int i=1 ; i<=ComboBox().getValue(); i++){
        TextField Text0 = ((TextField)getComponent (i, 0, table));
        TextField Text1 = ((TextField)getComponent (i, 1, table));
        TextField Text2 = ((TextField)getComponent (i, 2, table));
        TextField Text3 = ((TextField)getComponent (i, 3, table));
        TextField Text4 = ((TextField)getComponent (i, 4, table));
        TextField Text5 = ((TextField)getComponent (i, 5, table));
        TextField Text6 = ((TextField)getComponent (i, 6, table));
        TextField Text7 = ((TextField)getComponent (i, 7, table));

        System.out.println(Text0 + " " + Text1 + " " + Text2 + " " + Text3 + " " + Text4 + " " + Text5 + " " + Text6 + " " + Text7);

            }
    }
```

I want to achieve that because `anchorPane().getChildren().size()` will not always remain 0, it'll change during application's running state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Boolean binding for whether or not an observable list is empty:

```
BooleanBinding empty = Bindings.isEmpty(anchorPane.getChildren());
```

And then:

```
empty.addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> {
    if (! isNowEmpty) {
        // ...
    }
});
```